# Losing value when clicking on button in ascx control that is rendered in asp:Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I created a `asp:Repeater` that I fill with `.ascx` controls:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Repeater1.DataSource = listOfData;
    Repeater1.DataBind();            
}
```

On page I have:

```
<uc:Product runat="server"                                             
    ImportantData='<% #Eval("ImportantData") %>'                                               
    id="DetailPanel1" />
```

Inside `Product.ascx.cs` I have:

```
public int ImportantData{ get; set; }
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

On `Product.ascx` I have:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btn_Ok" runat="server" 
     onclick="btn_Ok_Click"  
     ImageUrl="~/image.png" />
```

Problem is when I click on image button I get error:

```
A critical error has occurred. Invalid postback or callback argument. Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page...
```

I have tried to change first code to this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        Repeater1.DataSource = listOfData;
        Repeater1.DataBind();            
    }
    // Repeater1.DataBind(); // and tried to put DataBind() here
}
```

But then when I click on image button `ImportantData` is empty.
What I did wrong here?

Comment: And where the `ImportantData` comes from? Are you sure objects from the bound list have it?

Comment: Have you tried to set EnableEventValidation="false"?

Comment: "that I fill with .ascx controls" Makes me suspicious. What's the listOfData contain, and how does that relate to the <uc:Product> ?

Comment: Can you please provide some feedback as to the suggested solutions or more information about your specific problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PageLoad is happening before your postback event, change your event to PreRender:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Repeater1.DataSource = listOfData;
    Repeater1.DataBind();            
}
```

This will bind your repeater after the postback and maintain your postback value.

**Edit:**

[Here's a good picture showing the entire WebForms page lifecycle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Knl1e.jpg):

As you can see

`ProcessPostData` event is called *AFTER* `Load` event.

So you want to bind your `Repeater` after the PostData has been processed.

This can be done on `PreRender`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that you are calling data bind in the wrong place, but most likely that the user control is not saving the data in viewstate correctly.  It looks like you are using a custom control.  What you can do if this is the case is to create a property on your user control that reads from the viewstate.  Here is an example:

```
Public Property ImportantData() As Int32
    Get
        Return ViewState("_ImportantData")
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Int32)
        ViewState("_ImportantData") = value
    End Set
End Property
```

This will allow your data to persist and the necessary data to be present on postback.

and doing this is correct so that it only loads on the initial load.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        Repeater1.DataSource = listOfData;
        Repeater1.DataBind();            
    }
    // Repeater1.DataBind(); // and tried to put DataBind() here
}
```

Comment: "The problem is not that you are calling data bind in the wrong place" <-- if you're not using viewstate, then yes its binding in the wrong place.

Comment: He has said nothing about viewstate at all.  I've inferred from experience that it he is using a custom control then he can ensure that it's persisting his properties which is his question.  If there is no viewstate then this needs to be done in the init stage actually (as someone who has written a fully dynamic app that does this).  If you bind after that then the value is missing when the event needs to be raised.  In fact if you rebind after this then you end up nullifying the event that the user wants to fire in the first place.

Comment: And if his issue is a viewstate issue (which I believe it is)  firing at pre-render will be too late and the value will still be missing.  I think that you misread his question, the problem is a missing value, not that the event doesn't fire.

Comment: So despite the fact I give a valid answer, and you don't seem to understand the page life-cycle. You decided to downvote me. Congrats!

Comment: If he implements your solution it will still not work.  I've already explained why.

Comment: You're wrong. End of story. His issue is easy to reproduce with the same error, moving the binding fixes it.